# R not erxact pattern matching with "or" and "any"

Tags: r

I have a problem, I can look for an exact string but I want to look for (as a first one but I want to modify it as well), I want to look for a pattern "K/any/D or E", I don't know how to write tthat sequence.

```
library(stringr)
#KXD/E 
ATR$pattern_KXDE <- str_detect(as.character(ATR$Sequence),"KAD")
```

Comment: Maybe you look for `K.(D|E)`

Comment: You will need to look at regular expressions ('regex'). R manual for this is [?regex](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html) and a helpful tool to learn is: [https://regexr.com/](https://regexr.com/).

Comment: Can you add some sample data and show expected output based on that?